# rake db:migrate doesnt work after paperclip gem is installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Hello guys im coding an instagram like app on rails, after i installed the paperclip gem (5.1) i created a model that i must migrate in the db. as i mentioned in the title the rake db:migrate doesnt work. i tried restarting the rails server and my laptop as suggested by some solutions, also tried adding the [5.1] next to the ActiveRecord::Migration like this as others suggested.

```
class CreatePics < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
```

after changing some versions it still doesnt work.
if its helpful the code project lies here https://github.com/leobouts/Instagramm

the error i get is

```
rake db:migrate --trace
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

Directly inheriting from ActiveRecord::Migration is not supported. Please specify the Rails release the migration was written for:

  class AddAttachmentImageToPics < ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]
/Users/leonidas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:525:in `inherited'
/Users/leonidas/Desktop/Instagramm/db/migrate/20170719181859_add_attachment_image_to_pics.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/leonidas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
```

and goes on and on like this

Comment: You should include the AddAttachmentImageToPics migration here

Comment: I guess the version number for the migration classes is only added in Rails 5. As you are using Rails 3, you should have the class names without version number. Try changing it to `class CreatePics < ActiveRecord::Migration` and `AddAttachmentImageToPics < ActiveRecord::Migration[4.2]` to `AddAttachmentImageToPics < ActiveRecord::Migration`

Comment: I suggest you reset your database : rake db:reset

Comment: thanks @Pavan this was exactly the issue, i'm getting a bit confused with the differences between the versions. I changed to the latest rails and used the version number for the migration classes.

Comment: Well, then I will add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your using **Rails 3**, the migration classes **should not** have `version number`. AFAIK, the `version number` for the migration classes is only added in **Rails 5.x** versions. Changing the classes should fix the error.

```
class CreatePics < ActiveRecord::Migration

class AddAttachmentImageToPics < ActiveRecord::Migration
```